# path = currentFile.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() Indexerror: List index out of range

Tags: python

I have to make a program RC5 encryption. I'm new to coding. I have finished my game, and during testing, everything works fine, but i get this error.

[image]

Comment: please post your code / error as a code block rather than an image - thanks :)

Comment: You are not showing the error that you get